# Transfer a folder using Rackspace File Cloud in PHP

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud

I want to transfer a folder containing different types of file from my server to Rackspace File Cloud using Rackspace File Cloud API for PHP.

Can i transfer a folder to Rackspace File Cloud? What is the corresponding php code for it?

Comment: The API Documentation should have all the code or at least the calls to do the requested

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a conclusion that we can't transfer a folder to Rackspace File Cloud but we can create containers where we can keep the files.